# Multiple different excel files simultaneously updating one table in a separate file

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know if there is any way to have multiple separate excel files all updating one master excel file?
The problem is that multiple users need to be updating a table at the same time, but when a file is opened on the network by one user, it is locked and cannot be edited by another user at the same time.
Right now I have a form that a user will enter data into and then after using a macro, the data will be sent to a separate sheet. I would like to have multiple files with this form, all sending data to one table in a separate file. And the form files need to all be able to send data simultaneously.

Comment: Store the data in a database. Excel spreadsheets are not good for this purpose.

Comment: @JacobH This was my first thought but unfortunately the clients only want to use excel spreadsheets, not work with databases

Comment: If you are the consultant then they are relying for you on your expertise. Tell them that due to the nature of Excel, this is not possible, as the files are locked by the user when they are opened. You don't really have much choice except to convey the truth to them.

Comment: @JacobH Ok, thanks. I was mostly wanting to confirm that this isn't possible in excel since I wasn't sure if it was or not. I will tell them that

Comment: No problem. I used to work in a similar role. It's a pretty common scenario (the users want to only work in Excel). Excel is a great tool, but as businesses grow they often need better tools, and using Excel as a centralized database is not what it was designed for. Maybe look into Access? It's very easy to integrate Excel and Access without much pain on the user.

Comment: If the issue is updating data in a table from multiple users on a network, you can create a shared Excel document that allows multiple users to edit it at once. There limitations to what you can do in a shared Excel file (lookup the official Microsoft documentation on "shared Excel workbook"), but depending what you need it may work fine. You could also utilize Power Query in Excel to easily aggregate data from other Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, I have done it several times.

The main issue that I have run into in the past is that the client quickly forgets that you can't keep the report file open, it will only go out and fetch data from the other files when it is opened.  Additionally they have to remember that these are static links, so the source files cannot me renamed or moved.

Comment: So each of the files could be open at once, each adding rows to a table in a separate file without losing any data along the way?

Comment: Yes ... people can have any number of the source files open and edit them ... but they would have to save and close the files before the master file is able to draw info from them.

Comment: I've set it up in a real estate office where the different realtors would maintain individual spreadsheets for properties in the regions they dealt with l, then had a master sheet that would draw upon the data in each of the regional files ... also setup in a couple of small construction companies to track their job bids, suppliers, and equipment ... then also at a bar so the owner could have multiple employees audit the liquer supply without seeing what each other had recorded ... the common theme was that all of the owners were cheap and didn't want to pay for industry standard software